# Creating a jQuery callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem understanding how to create a callback function which I can use to extend the options, as stated in this [guide](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/). Here's the excerpt of code that I want to use for callback;

```
var chart       =   {};
chart.data      =   $('.liselected').attr("data"); 
chart.command   =   $('.liselected').attr("cmd");
chart.option    =   "option"; // Category of event request
chart.sessionid =   docCookies.getItem("sessionid");
chart.ageType   =   selectedAgeType;
chart.showData  =   showUnderlyingData;

var action  =   function(result, status) {

    $('#thumbnails .error').remove();
    var chart_list  =   "";

    $.each(result, function(i, val){
        chart_list += //Custom HTML Output
    });

    $('#chart_view').html(chart_list);
};

$.post("jsoncommand", JSON.stringify(chart), action);
```

So that I can call using `$("a").on("click", postcommand(eventrequest))`, I tried creating a function like this;

```
$.fn.postcommand = function(){
    var settings = $.extend({
        item        :   {},
        data        :   $('.liselected').attr("data"),
        command     :   $('.liselected').attr("cmd"),
        option      :   "specify query",
        sessionid  :    docCookies.getItem("sessionid"),
        ageType     :   selectedAgeType,
        showData    :   showUnderlyingData,
    }, options );

    return //How do I make the output of HTML result is customizable?
};
```

But of course, my attempt is a failure. Spoon feeding is good, but you can always give me a hint and I'll try to explore on my own. Thanks!

Comment: `$("a").on("click", postcommand(eventrequest))` doesn't make sense unless `postcommand(eventrequest)` returns a function.

Comment: Of course. That's my question. I'm trying to create a function for that.

Comment: Where is your *"attempt"*? I see where you started to make a jquery plugin, but it's being assigned to the jquery.prototype rather than directly to jquery, and you aren't even using it in your code. And best of all, you didn't even attempt to build a function to return!

Comment: Also, your syntax for the object inside `extend` is incorrect; replace the `=` with `:`, and `;` with `,`.

Comment: @KevinB Thats why I'm here. I need a hint and your expert opinion. My attempt is half cooked. Maybe my question is wrong also. Forgive me for being so bad, but I'm still new to this.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a good idea to check out the jQuery plugin section: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/. You could do something like this:

```
$.fn.postcommand = function (options) {

    // define some default values for your plugin
    var default = {
        callback: function () {}
    }

    // merge default settings,  with the ones given  
    var settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );

    return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.on('click', function(event) {
          settings.callback();
          event.preventDefault();
        });
    }
});
```

And then use your plugin on some links:

```
$('a.useCallback').postcommand();
```